Can an std::istream be split without specifying the number of delimiters?
I have the separate_by_delimiter function which is used inside another function outside_func
std::vector<std::string>
separate_by_delimiter(std::istream &input, int num_separators, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> separated_list;
    std::string segment;
    std::stringstream input_stream;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_separators; i++) {
        std::getline(input, segment, delimiter);
        input_stream << segment << delimiter;
    }
    while (std::getline(input_stream, segment, delimiter)) {
        separated_list.insert(separated_list.begin(), segment);
    }
    return separated_list;
}

const int n = 10; // just as an example
void outside_func(std::istream &input) {
    auto split_list = separate_by_delimiter(input, n, ',');
    input >> x; // x defined earlier
}

As you can see separate_by_delimiter relies on how many separators (delimiters) are in the input so it can create a std::vector<std::string>  (not including the part after the last delimiter as it must be passed to another variable)
How can this be done without specifying the number of separators?

Your post title doesn't match your post body, You are asking two separate questions.  Can istream be split on a delimiter? Yes. Can you split an istream without specifying the number of delimiters? It depends on whether the stream data specifies where to stop reading. But since you did not show your input, it is difficult to answer this question. In any case, the code you showed does not need input_stream and 2 for loops. 1 for loop will suffice. Simply insert() on each iteration and then return when the loop is finished. How you know when to stop the loop depends on the input.

"How can this be done without specifying the number of separators?" -- How do you know when it's done? Not the computer, you. You are given a book (the input stream) and a character to treat as a delimiter. How do you know when to stop copying from the book?

If you have specifically formatted input then you can write code to read it. Otherwise there is no way to know when to stop reading it one way and start reading a different way. What pattern or signal have you to know when to change your input handling?

@Dúthomhas -- you don't need to read a stream in different ways. You read the stream until the end, and use the last token the way you like. If you absolutely have to have a stream, you can put the last token to a stream. If you absolutely have to have the original stream, then swap them.

If the delimiter can occur in the input after the desired number of elements, you can't do this without passing the number of elements to extract.
If you know that the delimiter occurs at most enough times in the input to gather your elements, then you don't need the number at all.
N.b. you don't need to copy the data into a stringstream, you can add it to the result directly.
std::vector<std::string>
separate_by_delimiter(std::istream &input, int num_separators, char delimiter) {
    std::vector<std::string> separated_list;
    for (std::string segment; (num_separators-- > 0) && std::getline(input, segment, delimiter); ) {
        separated_list.insert(separated_list.begin(), segment);
    }
    return separated_list;
}


If my guess is correct, what you are trying to do is to tokenize the input by specifying a delimiter between the tokens, and treat the last token separately by removing it from the token vector and assigning it to a variable x.
Below is an example how to do that.
template<class T>
auto tokenize(std::basic_istream<T>& input, T separator)
{
    std::vector<std::basic_string<T>> tokens;
    
    auto last_eof = false;
    for (std::basic_string<T> token; std::getline(input, token, separator); last_eof = input.eof())
        tokens.push_back(std::move(token));

    if(!last_eof) // separator is the last character
        tokens.emplace_back();
    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("1,2,3,4,5,6");

    auto ts = tokenize(iss, ',');
    std::cout << "size: "<< ts.size() << "\n";
    auto x = ts.back();
    std:: cout << "x: " << x << "\n";
    ts.resize(ts.size() - 1);
    std::cout << "tokens: ";
    for(auto s : ts)
        std::cout << s << " ";
}

I corrected my previous solution to include empty token when the separator is the last character in the stream. If that is not what is desired then everything about last_eof can be deleted.

This code reads the input until either eof is reached or an error occurs. The OP clearly wants to read delimiters for only a portion of the input, and then read non-delimited data after. They just need help determining when to stop reading delimiters.

@Remy Lebeau -- let the OP talk for himself, I made a guess, have patience to let him comment.

the OP already stated their intention in their question. No need to guess. This kind of tokenizing code is fine if the input contains ONLY delimited tokens. But the OP wants to read more data AFTER the last delimiter. They made that clear up front. And this code doesn't handle that, unless the caller had already split the input beforehand, which they clearly hadn't. So I DV'ed for providing an answer that can't be applied to the question asked.

@Remy Lebeau - I politely disagree, the OP's question is not clear and requires guesswork.

"not including the part after the last delimiter as it must be passed to another variable" - means the input has more data that the function in question must not read yet. "input >> x" - shows more data being read after the function in question exits. So the function in question must stop reading when the last delimiter is reached. Not much room for guessing. The intent is clear, the solution is not clear, without knowing what the input actually looks like.

@Remy Lebeau - that's not unambiguous statement. What does it mean not including the part after the last delimiter? Are you saying the last token should be removed from the vector and copied elsewhere?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Since you asked for explanations: downvoted because you didn't explain the most important thing: that it was impossible to do what OP wanted, so you did the next best thing. Also you fixed some bugs but didn't explain that.

@anatolyg -- explain, provide example. If my guess in the answer is correct, I don't see how that is impossible.

What about the case where the input stream never ends (like std::cin)?
